# How can i deploy a zip whit maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven

I develop a web application that has two layers: a frontend layer and a backend. I deployed the backend war in artifactory using distributionManagement. Now I want to deploy the frontend. I use maven assembly plugin. I made a zip. I would like to know how to deploy the frontend zip in artifactory?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: How have you using the maven assembly plugin ? How do your pom files look like?

Comment: <!-- Maven assembly plugin -->
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>myArchive</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
       </descriptors>
       <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How deploy a zip file whith Maven assembly plugin in the artifactory referentiel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757176/how-deploy-a-zip-file-whith-maven-assembly-plugin-in-the-artifactory-referentiel)